# How to set Z-Index order in react tailiwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

I am newbie in tailwind. And i have page like this below
[image]

This build using React and Tailwind, do you know how to set the backdrop on this modal so it can be full for all screen?

Below my current code:

```
 <div className="rounded bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800 mb-4 mt-8 p-8">
        <h2 className="text-4xl font-extrabold dark:text-white mb-10">
          {t("text.add_event-agenda")}
        </h2>
        <div>
          <br />
          <div className="flex flex-row w-full py-2">
            <button
              onClick={handleClickAdd}
              className="text-white w-full bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
            >
              {t(" Add Schedule")}
            </button>
          </div>
          <br />
                 </div>
      </div>

      {/* Modal Add Agenda */}
      <div
        id="modalEl"
        tabIndex={-1}
        aria-hidden="true"
        className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50 hidden w-full p-4 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto md:inset-0 h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full"
      >
        <div className="relative w-full max-w-md max-h-full">
          {/* <!-- Modal content --> */}
          <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="absolute top-3 right-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 ml-auto inline-flex justify-center items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
              data-modal-hide="authentication-modal"
            >
              <svg
                className="w-3 h-3"
                aria-hidden="true"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 14 14"
              >
                <path
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-width="2"
                  d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"
                />
              </svg>
              <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
            </button>
            <div className="px-6 py-6 lg:px-8">
              <h3 className="mb-4 text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                Sign in to our platform
              </h3>
              <div className="flex flex-col">
                {/* Agenda Title */}
                <EVSInput
                  t={t}
                  label="label.agenda-name"
                  type="text"
                  name="eventAgenda.name"
                  placeholder="label.agenda-name"
                />
                {/* Agenda Session */}
                <EVSInput
                  t={t}
                  label="label.session-name"
                  type="text"
                  name="eventAgenda.sessionName"
                  placeholder="label.session-name"
                />
                {/* Agenda Speaker */}
                <EVSInput
                  t={t}
                  label="label.agenda-speaker"
                  type="text"
                  name="eventAgenda.speaker"
                  placeholder="label.agenda-speaker"
                />
                <div className="flex flex-row gap-3">
                  {/* Agenda Start */}
                  <div>
                    <label
                      htmlFor="text"
                      className="block py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
                    >
                      {"label.start-time"}
                    </label>
                    <Flatpickr
                      name="eventAgenda.start"
                      className="py-2 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                      options={{
                        enableTime: true,
                        noCalendar: true,
                        dateFormat: "H:i",
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                  {/* Agenda End */}
                  <div>
                    <label
                      htmlFor="text"
                      className="block py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
                    >
                      {"label.end-time"}
                    </label>
                    <Flatpickr
                      name="eventAgenda.end"
                      className="py-2 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                      options={{
                        enableTime: true,
                        noCalendar: true,
                        dateFormat: "H:i",
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

                {/* Event Agenda Descriptions */}
                <EVSTextArea
                  t={t}
                  label="label.agenda-descriptions"
                  name="eventAgenda.descriptions"
                  placeholder="label.agenda-descriptions"
                  className="md:col-span-2"
                  rows={3}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And this

```
function initModal() {
    const $modalElementAdd = document.querySelector("#modalEl") as HTMLElement;

    const modalOptions: ModalOptions = {
      placement: "center",
      backdrop: "dynamic",
      backdropClasses:
        "bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 dark:bg-opacity-80 fixed inset-0 z-40",
      closable: true,
    };
    return {
      $modalElementAdd,
      modalOptions,
    };
  }
  function handleClickAdd() {
    const modalOptions = initModal().modalOptions;
    const $modalElementAdd = initModal().$modalElementAdd;
    const modal: ModalInterface = new Modal($modalElementAdd, modalOptions);

    modal.show();
  }
```

I have used z-50 for backdrop and main content of modal but it block all screen, what i ask is, how to set this modal as the first layer on the screen when button was clicked?